# Connect Ruby on Rails Application to an ESB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, esb

I want to connect a ruby on rails application with to an ESB. Is it possible to connect a Ruby application with an ESB?

Please provide explanations and suggestions.

Comment: ... Obviously it depends on the ESB. Any I've used can consume from a message queue like RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Please notice that Ruby is soft-typed and that EBS services should (normally) be strong typed, so that you will probably require manual type checking.

Ruby could probably be used for most applications (not system writing) and it definitely fits well within a Service oriented design such as an EBS.